# C# Need Help on Converting String to Int?

Tags: c#, textbox

So... I have this section of code here, everything seems perfect but when I try to run this, it gives a formatting exception handler error.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != null)
        {
            minusTime = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); // fix this... idk what's even wrong. Just trying to assign user input to minusTime...
        }
        else
        {
            minusTime = 0;
        }
    }
```

*Note: textbox1 is user input of an integer value. minusTime is a null integer that is to be assigned to the user input.

I've tried running this with just "Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)" but it still gives me an exception saying the user inputted a wrong format... when the user input is clearly an int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want

```
bool result = Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out minusTime);
```

This will cope if the input isn't an integer returning `false`.

[MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

There is [another overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27.aspx) that takes in more information about the possible format of the number:

```
public static bool TryParse(
    string s,
    NumberStyles style,
    IFormatProvider provider,
    out int result
    )
```

This will cope with currency symbols etc.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! Thanks for getting rid of my headache, haha!

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
minusTime = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Also, change this line to `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))`

Comment: [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) is another similar solution

Comment: Thanks! This worked out great too! This is much simpler than what I was banging my head over...

Answer (score 1):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var minusTime;
    if (textBox1.Text != null && int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out minusTime))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        minusTime = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
int minusTime=0;
Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out minusTime);
```

minusTime will be 0 if textBox1.Text is not integer or even if it is null.